# How to add multiple middleware to Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware, redux-thunk

I have one piece of middleware already plugged in, **redux-thunk**, and I'd like to add another, **redux-logger**.

How do I configure it so my app uses both pieces of middleware? I tried passing in an array of `[ReduxThunk, logger]` but that didn't work.

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';
require('./style.scss');

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

[applyMiddleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html) takes each piece of middleware as a new argument (not an array). So just pass in each piece of middleware you'd like.

```
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk, logger)(createStore);
```

Comment: That was simple enough. Thank you!

Comment: and how do you pass the reducer to the createStore method?

Answer (score 32):

answer of andy's is good,
but, consider your middlewares growing,
below codes will be better:

```
const middlewares = [ReduxThunk, logger]
applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
```

Comment: Thank you, but i add redux-thunk
`const store = createStore(reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk, ...middleware)));`

Comment: Initial post stated that array was not working with redux_thunk...same issue for me

Answer (score 12):

`applyMiddleware` should pass into createStore as the second parameter. `applyMiddleware` can have multiple middlewares as arguments.

```
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk, logger));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

Comment: If I do this I get "createStore is not a function". Any idea where this error could be coming from? I'm trying to use redux-saga and remote-redux-devtools

Comment: Probably you are not importing `createStore` correctly or using an old version of redux.

Comment: the problem was that one of the middleware didn't need `applyMiddleware`, so I had to use `compose(applyMiddleware(saga), devtools())`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**This is how to apply one or many middlewares :**

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import {rootReducer} from "../reducers"; // Import your combined reducers ;)

const middleWares = [thunk, logger]; // Put the list of third part plugins in an array 

// Create the store with the applied middleWares and export it
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleWares));
```

**Now import the store exported recently in your index.js and pass it to the Provider component.
Your index.js file should looks like :**

...
...

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './store';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

That's all !

Comment: very complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

it may be a bit late of an answer but my problem was adding the devtools with the middlewares, hope this helps somebody

```
 // imports.. 
 import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";

  const store = createStore(
     Reducer,
     persistedState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk, promiseMiddleware))
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the middlewares in the comma separated manner like the following code:

`const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk, logger));`

Note: Please import the applyMiddlware, thunk, and logger at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    products: productReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
    [productsApi.reducerPath]: productsApi.reducer,
    userAuth: authSlice,
  },

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false
    }).concat(productsApi.middleware),

});
```